# how to do db.collection.aggregate() via mongodb-wire-protocol (OP_QUERY)?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How can i do this via mogoDB wire driver :

```
db.collection.aggregate(
   [
      { $match: <query condition> },
      { $group: { _id: null, count: { $sum: 1 } } }
   ]
)
```

Especially how to build the Query string ?

i need this because: to avoid on a sharded cluster that count can result in an inaccurate count if orphaned documents exist, we must use the $group stage of the db.collection.aggregate() method to $sum the documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to using the wire protocol, the wrapper methods provided by drivers can appear to be very removed from the protocol.  For instance, db.collection.aggregate () :
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/

However when you look under the aggregate dbcmd, it gives you more clues:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/aggregate/#dbcmd.aggregate

So for example, if you have a wire protocol driver that implements OP_QUERY, then for a database DB_name with collection COLL_name containing documents having a field DOC_NAME with another field that's an array of items called DOC_ITEMS, you can perform an aggregation query such as the pseudo-protocol below:

```
OP_QUERY - DB=DB_name, COLL=$cmd
#skip=0
#return=1
query:{
    "aggregate": "COLL_name",
    "pipeline": [
        {
        "$project": {
            "n_items": {
                "$size": "$DOC_ITEMS"
            },
            "DOC_NAME": 1
        }
    }
    ]
}
fields:{
}
```

If your library provides objects and arrays with key-value "Put" operations, the query is constructed by the following procedure:

```
Pipeline = new Array();
ProjectionItems = new Object();

Size = new Object();
Size.Put ("$size", "$DOC_ITEMS");

//calculated field
ProjectionItems.Put ("n_items", Size);              

//include "DOC_NAME" field in result projection
ProjectionItems.Put ("DOC_NAME", 1);            

Projection_PipelineCmd = new Object();
Projection_PipelineCmd.Put ("$project", ProjectionItems);

//add the projection definition to the pipeline array
Pipeline.Put (Projection_PipelineCmd);

Query = new Object();
Query.Put ("aggregate", "COLL_name");
Query.Put ("pipeline", Pipeline);
```

Hope this points you in the right direction!

Comment: Um, whoever issued the downvote it would be courteous for you to add a comment to indicate why.....